# Find out who and how last updated the table?

Tags: oracle, ddl

I need to find out who executed last `alter table` statement on the certain table and what was the statement itself. Using "Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Prod"

I found the date of last ddl modification:

```
select last_ddl_time from dba_objects where object_name = 'table1'
```

Comment: Is this DDL modification in the past? If so you might be in trouble if you don't have auditing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If auditing is not enabled you might have to dive into [logminer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96521/logminer.htm)